# im unable to access the index of an array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
 
export default function Room(room) {
    const { name, slug, price, images } = room;
    return (
        <article className='room'>
           <div className='img-container'>
               <img src={images[0]} alt='single room'/>  // here the error pops out
           </div>
        </article>
    )
}
```

im learning from a youtube source since its working in the tutorial but when I try to do the same it shows error of
{{{TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined}}} since im new as I mentioned before how to access the index of arrays in react

Comment: `<img src={images?.[0]} alt='single room'/>`

Comment: If you want to access the images array, use `map` for iterate and display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `?.` this is shorthand operator to check the dependency in any object. So if the `images` has more than 1 item it will work

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
 
export default function Room(room) {
    const { name, slug, price, images } = room;
    return (
        <article className='room'>
           <div className='img-container'>
               <img src={images?.[0]} alt='single room'/>  // here the error pops out
           </div>
        </article>
    )
}
```

Comment: since i used the shorthand opreator im getting back the alternative of ""single room"" its not rendering the image.

Comment: let images = item.fields.images.map((image) => {
        return image.fields.file.url;

Comment: images: [
        {
          fields: {
            file: {
              url: img2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          fields: {
            file: {
              url: room2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          fields: {
            file: {
              url: room3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          fields: {
            file: {
              url: room4
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },

Comment: Can you try console `console.log(images)` just above return

Comment: console logged {{{3 undefined}}}

Comment: That means you are not passing the props `images ` to your component properly

Answer (score 0):

looks like rooms.images does not exists/null.
check images existence before use it:

```html
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
 
export default function Room(room) {
    const { name, slug, price, images } = room;
    return (
        <article className='room'>
           <div className='img-container'>
               {images && images.lenght > 0 && <img src={images[0]} alt='single room'/>}
           </div>
        </article>
    )
}
```